# C++ - strcpy_s argument errors

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm getting some errors when using strcpy_s and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

Player.hpp:

```
string name;
Player(string);
```

Player.cpp:

```
Player::Player(string newName)
{
    strcpy_s(name, name.size(), newName);//error is here
    health = 20;
}
```

The errors:

- Too many arguments in function call
- No instance of overloaded function 'strcpy_s' matches the argument list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `strcpy_s` to copy `std::string`. Actually, you just need to do:

```
Player::Player(string newName) {
    name = newName;
    health = 20;
}
```

Even better, you could use a [constructor initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html):

```
Player::Player(string newName) : name(newName), health(20) {}
```

As a reference, here you have a detailed description of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

Comment: Oh! So you only need to use strcpy when you're using char*s?

Comment: You never need to use `strcpy`. But if `strcpy` happens to do what you need to do, you can use it. In this case, though, it doesn't do what you need to do because you don't yet have anything to copy the string into.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, you could resize the string and then use strcpy on the internal array, but that's just crazy, isn't it? :)

Comment: @betabandido: Exactly. So if a function doesn't do anything like what you want, it's probably not what you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

This URL states that the C++ version only uses template overloaded
functions (2 arguments not 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

template 
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char (&strDestination)[size],
   const char *strSource 
); // C++ only

According to this URL:

In C++, using these functions is simplified by template overloads; the overloads can infer buffer length automatically (eliminating the need to specify a size argument) and they can automatically replace older, non-secure functions with their newer, secure counterparts. For more information, see Secure Template Overloads.

(As stated in the prototype this function is for char* arguments - not for string data types)